# Linux Wordpress can't not write wp-config file

Tags: linux, wordpress, file-permissions

I installed the latest version of Apache2 / PHP / MYSQL on my pc

In the directory /srv/www/htdocs I created a directory wordpress with all wordpress file.

Then, when I tried to create the wp-config file through the web interface I get this error :

```
Sorry, but i can't write the wp-config file.
```

I tried this command to change the group of `/src/www/htdocs/wordpress`

```
chown -R root:root /srv/www/htdocs/wordpress
```

But it was not working. After some research, i seen lot of people saying to change the group to `www-data` but i do not see `www-data` using this commande :

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/group
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

[image]
[image]

Sorry about my poor english.

Comment: I see a group called `www` in your listing.  That might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 11):

This is what worked for me. (I'm a beginner and I'm using Debian 8)

First I checked the Apache config file to find the group that apache uses. In my case it was www-data.
`grep ^Group /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

I checked my /etc/group file and the group www-data was there.

Then I changed the group ownership of my wordpress directory from root to www-data.

```
chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress
```

I changed the permissions of my wordpress folder to 755 for directories and 644 for files, following the recommendations of other sites.

```
find /var/www/html/wordpress -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/html/wordpress -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

But since we want to give write permissions to the group www-admin for the wordpress folder and subfolders, I changed the permissions for directories to 775:

```
find /var/www/html/wordpress -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

**Then it worked**: All right, sparky! You’ve made it through this part of the installation. WordPress can now communicate with your database. If you are ready, time now to…

Notes: The username and password of my myssql database was root/root. The username I was using to login to my computer was root and the password was something different than root. Just in case I changed my password to root, so the credentials of mysql and my local account are the same. I don't know if by having the same name (root) they are the same account.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like `www-data` is not the group name used by apache on your system. To find what it actually uses, try the following:

```
ps xO gid | head -n 1; ps xO gid | grep httpd
```

(That's a capital O, not a zero). The column GID (probably the second column) is the numeric group ID that apache is running under. Look up its name in `/etc/group`.

Comment: The GID return 0, does that mean there is none ? You can check picture in my original post

Comment: Group id zero is almost certainly the group that `root` belongs to. Do look it up in `/etc/group`, it's the third column. It might be called `root`, or `staff` or `wheel` (or something else, who knows). It might be a good idea, though, to run apache with fewer privileges... if you can figure out how.

Comment: Yeah, zero is root. Root have all privileges and the directory /srv/www/htdocs is set to the root group. Why i still don't have the privilege to write the wp-config file using the web interface of wordpress

Comment: Don't confuse root group with root uid. But indeed it looks like a process with gid 0 should be able to _create_ files in the `wordpress` subdirectory (since the group-write permission bit is set). Either the file exists already and is not writable by group zero, or apache (or wordpress) is taking special steps to rein in group zero permissions-- it's really not a good idea to run apache that way.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I implemented CHOWN & CHMOD steps, but the issue was still persisting, then I found another scenario where this/same error could occur because of **SELINUX CONTEXT** issue (*lack of write permission context*).

To solve that - You can change Apache/HTTPD **write context** with in the web-content folder like this (Specific to the Debian environment, as mentioned in this question):

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t  /src/www/htdocs
```

OR (on CentOS/Fedora):

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t  /var/www/html
```

You can validate the output like this (on CentOS/Fedora):

```
# pwd
# /var/www
```

Notice the output of below command having *changed* RW (Read/Write) context on **html** (web-content) folder:

```
# ls -ltrZ
# drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t:s0 4096 Jul  9 20:45 cgi-bin
# drwxrwxr-x. 5 apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0  4096 Jul 14 19:28 html
```

**NOTE: Do validate the Path, Web Server User-Names, and SELINUX write-context as per your environment before executing above commands.**

Comment: By usung `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t  /var/www/html` it spit out **chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/var/www/html' ....**

Comment: According other threads on Unix Stackexchange: "chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/var/www/html'", it is necessary to label the files using 'semanage' and if there is SELinux in enforcing mode.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was missing. I had permissions all set correctly and couldn't for the life of my figure out what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

> ## unable to write to wp-config.php file.

I had this problem in my `ubuntu 20.04`, `WordPress 5.x`. I solved this issue with these steps:

- First, change the group ownership of the WordPress directory from root to www-data.

```
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress
```

- Then change your WordPress folders permission by this command.

```
sudo find /var/www/html/wordpress -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

- Then change your WordPress files permission by this command.

```
sudo find /var/www/html/wordpress -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

- Run the installation again.

Answer (score -4):

You have to need permission..... Just open the terminal and execute: `sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/yourfolder`

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Z3J.png)

Comment: Do **not** do this.  This will give every user/process on your system rwx access to your entire site.